Film about seeing into the past
I'm looking for the name of a film where the plot revolves around some technology that the government have for "seeing" 2 or 3 days into the past. The non-spoiler version of the story is that they are collecting a vast amount of data from satellites around the planet and can see events happening anywhere in the world in high quality a couple of days after it happens.
The event that the protagonists are trying to determine the cause of is the explosion of a ship full of US military personnel on some form of parade/show.
Spoiler details:

This turns out to be a window into the past rather than just a recording of the past and someone can get sent back through it to try and prevent it from happening as well as solve it


Déjà Vu (2006), starring Denzel Washington. At Mardi Gras in New Orleans a ferry carrying US Navy soldiers from the docks to a celebration is blown up by a car bomb. An ATF agent (Washington) examines the case. The body of a woman is found which seems to be connected to the explosion but raises the agent's suspicion. When he examines her flat he finds further evidence for a connection. When reporting his findings he is referred to a special unit that has the technology you describe.
